# No sound in (connected) Bluetooth earphones 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth

My Bluetooth earphones are connected to my device but the sound is coming from the speakers. I set the output device to *Bluetooth earphones* and installed `blueman`, but it doesn't work.

I managed to get the right output in a video played by VLC though.

Also, the system sounds (volume indicator -little sound played when volume up-, alert sound) outputs to my earphones.

Everything works fine in Manjaro though.

How can I get this basic functionality to work?

Answer (score 2):

Just solved the same problem you're having. All I had to do was installing pulseaudio through apt, with:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

Then you'll need to go to the **Configuration** tab and set the Bluetooth headphone profile to *High Fidelity Audio Playback (A2DP Sink)*.
[image: configuration tab in the app pulseaudio]

now, if you want to, you can go to the tab **Output devices** and set the fallback to be your headphone. do this by clicking in the green sign of check:
[image: output devices tab in the app pulseaudio: setting headphone as fallback]

you should also make sure that to set the output of the apps you want to your phone, in the tab **Playback**:
[image: playback tab in the app pulseaudio]
notice that, my earphone, bw-fye7, is selected as output device for firefox audio. If you want, for example, to listen to firefox audio in your headphone, to popcorn-time audio in your device connected to HDMI and to some video in your laptop, you'll just need to select the right output device for each app.